# making sprinkles for donut in blender

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I am following blender guru tutorial to make donut . however while making sprinkles the top part is not becoming flat like the blender guru did in his tutorial.... though i am following all his steps still. here's the images for clear perspective..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcmLm.png)

[image]

Comment: if he's beveling and it's not working as expected for you, maybe you need to apply the scale of your object in Object mode (Ctrl A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to bevel your sprinkle try to select the object and press control+A on your keypad first in **object mode**  and press apply scale then try bevelling it again it should work

in case you are a beginner, these images will help you comprehend

[image]

[image]

These two objects are bevelled with the same value and look at the difference if you don't apply the scale of your object#

TIP: **ALWAYS APPLY YOUR SCALE OR ROTATION OF YOUR OBJECT BEFORE ROTATING OR SCALING
OR ELSE ACTIONS WILL BE PERFORMED DIFFERENTLY ON YOUR MESH**

**** PLEASE REMEMBER  FIRST APPLY THE SCALE THEN TRY BEVELLING AGAIN PLS DONT APPLY SCALE AFTER BEVELLING OR ELSE YOUR PROBLEM WON`T BE SOLVED****

HOPE THIS HELPED

Comment: yes , thank you very much